# AWS CLI for EBS snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get AWS CLI going to backup my EC2 instances. I can't see why AWS don't make it easy to schedule this via the console but they don't so I am pushing ahead with CLI.

I installed on one of my instances. Problem 1, it won't work unless I setup a NAT instance as my instance has no public IP. Trying to avoid that so I used a server at a different ISP that does have a public IP. I setup the credentials and profiles using aws configure. I have config and credentials files in .aws directory. All should work. I try:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile tmpevaluate

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com/"
```

I tried

```
nslookup ec2.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com
```

but it doesn't resolve. Weird as it resolves on my Mac and DNS is working on the server I am trying it from as it can resolve any other domains I can think of. So to debug I installed and configured AWS CLI on my Mac. I know it can resolve ec2.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com. So I tried:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile tmpevaluate
```

and get:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c0ac6d0>, 'Connection to ec2.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

I am at a loss. Something that should be so simple has me totally stumped and no one else seems to be having the same problem.

Ideas?

Comment: Look at third party applications like CloudMGR (http://www.cloudmgr.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`us-west-2`** instead of **`us-west-2b`** in your Endpoint URL. Most probably, this would be the value of `REGION` in your configuration file that was created by running `aws configure`

**`us-west-2`** is a region
**`us-west-2b`** is an availability Zone in that region.

You should be connecting to the Region and not to a specific Availability Zone